# e to the pi gives 1.0 and I am unable to comprehend the why behind it. Need help in understanding the underlying science

Tags: python-3.x, math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, pymatlab

I created a simple function to solve e to the power pi explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dhHrg-KbJ0)

```
def e_to_power_pi(number):
    return (1 + (1/number)) ** (number * math.pi)
```

from the look of it, clearly simple piece of code. But look at the output difference of these two values:

Example one:

```
e_to_power_pi(1000000000000000)
```

output:

```
32.71613881872869
```

Example Two:

```
e_to_power_pi(10000000000000000)
```

output:

```
1.0
```

upon tear down of the code, I learnt that 1.0 is coming from this portion 
**1 + (1/number)** of the code above.

When I tore it down further, I learnt that `1/10000000000000000` outputs correct answer as it should `0.00000000000000001`.

But when I add `1` to result it returns `1.0` instead of `1.00000000000000001`.

I presumed that it must be default round off in python that may be changing the value.

I decided to use `round(<float>, 64) # where <float> is any computation taking place in code above` to try and get 64 digits post decimal result. But still I got stuck with the same result when addition was performed i.e. `1.0`.

Can someone guide me or point me to the direction where I can learn or further read about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double-precision binary floating-point format, with 53-bit significand precision, which is not quite enough to represent your fraction:

```
10000000000000001/10000000000000000 = 1.0000000000000001
```

See [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)

Mathematica can operate in precisions higher than the architecturally imposed machine precision.

See [Wolfram Language: MachinePrecision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html)

The Mathematica screenshot below shows you would need a significand precision *higher* than 53-bit to obtain a result other than 1.

`N` numericises the fractional result to the requested precision.  Machine precision is the default; higher precision calculations are done in software.

[image]

Comment: Thank you It was really helpful. I now understand what is limiting my computer or my friend's laptop